# Crash between react-native-navigation and yarn-workspace

Tags: react-native, yarn-workspaces, wix-react-native-navigation

### Bug Report

Hello
My project with Yarn Workspace crashes once I add RNN. I tried with and without Yarn Workspace and it seems to be the issue. I made a demo for testing purpose.
Know that I tried this several times.

### To Reproduce

Step 1: install react-native

Step 2: Configure yarn workspace for RN with 2 packages (see demo: package.json files and metro.config.js).

Step 3: `yarn add react-native-navigation` in one repo

Step 4: `npx rnn-link` (each step is successful)

Step 5: change index.js to have RNN deal with the App Launch with one route

Step 6: `pod install`

Step 7: run project with XCode or with `yarn android`

### Expected behavior

Working on both platform.

### Actual Behavior

Android: black screen loading instead of the splashscreen for a few seconds, then crashes with those weird logs.
iOS crashes faster with (mostly) the same logs:

```
ERROR  Invariant Violation: No callback found with cbID 0 and callID 0 for module <unknown>. Args: '[{"app_state":"active"}]'
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: No callback found with cbID 6 and callID 3 for module <unknown>. Args: '[{"app_state":"active"}]'
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: No callback found with cbID 60 and callID 30 for module <unknown>. Args: '["{\"codeFrame\":{\"content\":\"\\u001b[0m \\u001b[90m 36 |\\u001b[39m       \\u001b[36mvar\\u001b[39m args \\u00...(truncated)..."]'
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: No callback found with cbID 62 and callID 31 for module <unknown>. Args: '["{\"codeFrame\":{\"content\":\"\\u001b[0m \\u001b[90m 20 |\\u001b[39m   }\\u001b[0m\\n\\u001b[0m \\u001b[90m 21 |...(truncated)..."]'
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: No callback found with cbID 68 and callID 34 for module <unknown>. Args: '["{\"codeFrame\":{\"content\":\"\\u001b[0m \\u001b[90m 36 |\\u001b[39m       \\u001b[36mvar\\u001b[39m args \\u00...(truncated)..."]'
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: No callback found with cbID 98 and callID 49 for module <unknown>. Args: '["{\"codeFrame\":{\"content\":\"\\u001b[0m \\u001b[90m 20 |\\u001b[39m   }\\u001b[0m\\n\\u001b[0m \\u001b[90m 21 |...(truncated)..."]'
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: No callback found with cbID 102 and callID 51 for module <unknown>. Args: '["{\"codeFrame\":{\"content\":\"\\u001b[0m \\u001b[90m 36 |\\u001b[39m       \\u001b[36mvar\\u001b[39m args \\u00...(truncated)..."]'
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: No callback found with cbID 16 and callID 8 for module <unknown>. Args: '["Stack2"]'
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: No callback found with cbID 138 and callID 69 for module <unknown>. Args: '["{\"codeFrame\":{\"content\":\"\\u001b[0m \\u001b[90m 36 |\\u001b[39m       \\u001b[36mvar\\u001b[39m args \\u00...(truncated)..."]'
 LOG  Running "com.myApp.WelcomeScreen" with {"initialProps":{"componentId":"Component1"},"rootTag":1}
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: No callback found with cbID 160 and callID 80 for module <unknown>. Args: '["{\"codeFrame\":{\"content\":\"\\u001b[0m \\u001b[90m 20 |\\u001b[39m   }\\u001b[0m\\n\\u001b[0m \\u001b[90m 21 |...(truncated)..."]'
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: No callback found with cbID 164 and callID 82 for module <unknown>. Args: '["{\"codeFrame\":{\"content\":\"\\u001b[0m \\u001b[90m 36 |\\u001b[39m       \\u001b[36mvar\\u001b[39m args \\u00...(truncated)..."]'
and it goes on and on and on...
```

### Your Environment

- React Native Navigation version: 7.14.0
- React Native version: 0.64.0
- Device info: Xiaomi Redmi Note 7 or Android Emulator or Xcode Simulator

### Reproducible Demo

https://gitlab.com/kanso-team/rnn-yw-repro

Any clue appreciated.
Maybe it is related to my config of yarn workspace, but my config works normally without RNN...

Answer (score 1):

For those interested, I fixed it in my yarn workspace configuration. In my package.json:

```
"nohoist": [ "**/*/**" ]
```