# Invariant Violation: no callback found with cbID for module<unknown>

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, npm, yarnpkg

I have created yarn package with common components, services, utils, etc. for my project. Then I have created index.ts file in src folder, where I've exported all components. Then I've built the package, added to my project. Then if I import a component from the package after starting the app in a real device or in an emulator, it's all OK. But if I import component first and then start app with `react-native run-android` (or `-ios`), I get a lot of errors `Invariant Violation: no callback found with cbID for module<unknown>` in loop:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any solution found for this?

Comment: @Mohanakrrishna Unfortunately, no :(

Comment: Are you sure you didnt open tab with debugger twice.

Comment: Additionally, since it says that the module is unknown it could also be from the missing dependencies from that don't add to Podfile automatically. So you have to manually add them because your linker seems to have some issues

Answer (score 4):

Just fixed it. You need to make sure the react-native version is compatible with the react-native version of your dependencies.

For example: your project: react-native: 0.65, but your dependency: 0.64. You will get this error.

Answer (score 1):

In my case this was due to a mismatch between the JS react-native version and the native version.

Near the top of the logs was the message below. Running `watchman watch-del-all && react-native start --reset-cache` as suggested in the log message fixed the issue.

```
2021-12-13 12:09:04.781041-0800 example[32395:987769] [javascript] React Native version mismatch.

JavaScript version: 0.63.4
Native version: 0.66.4

Make sure that you have rebuilt the native code. If the problem persists try clearing the Watchman and packager caches with `watchman watch-del-all && react-native start --reset-cache`.
2021-12-13 12:09:04.856943-0800 example[32395:987769] [javascript] Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
2021-12-13 12:09:04.859616-0800 example[32395:987758] [connection] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C6.1:1] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove node_modules and try again. It resolved the issue for me

```
rm -rf node_modules 
npm install --save
```

Comment: Or if you have another warning before AppRegistry failed to load, it would be helpful if you share that warning too because AppRegistry failed to load should have an error warning

Answer (score 0):

I looked into this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67771127/1551102), and found that this actually works for RN navigation 6 I fixed it in my yarn workspace configuration as per the answer. In my package.json I added at the end.

Then I deleted the node_modules folder

And then rebuild the project and the error was gone.

```
"nohoist": [ "**/*/**" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

yep, faced the same issue and resolved it with changing `peerDependencies` in my library. what i did:

in the library directory:

1. in package.json changed `peerDependencies` versions to `*`
2. `npm publish`

in the project directory:

1. `rm -Rf node_modules && yarn install`
2. `yarn add your-package-name`

now everything works like a charm